# Reading DSA private key protected with 3DES

Tags: c++, openssl

Here is how I manage to create the key pair and store in files successfully. The problem comes when reading the private key protected with password where I always get NULL. Any tip to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
FILE *dsa_privatekey_file;
FILE *dsa_publickey_file;

const char *pkeykey = "password";

int result = 0;

DeleteFile("dsapub.pem");
DeleteFile("dsapriv.pem");

dsa_publickey_file = fopen("dsapub.pem", "r");
dsa_privatekey_file = fopen("dsapriv.pem", "r");

if (dsa_privatekey_file == NULL || dsa_publickey_file == NULL)
{
    if (dsa_privatekey_file != NULL)
    {
        fclose(dsa_privatekey_file);
    }
    if (dsa_publickey_file != NULL)
    {
        fclose(dsa_publickey_file);
    }

    dsa_publickey_file = fopen("dsapub.pem", "w");
    dsa_privatekey_file = fopen("dsapriv.pem", "w");

    DSA* dsa = DSA_new();
    result = DSA_generate_parameters_ex(dsa, 2048, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    result = DSA_generate_key(dsa);

    result = PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey(dsa_privatekey_file, dsa, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), NULL, 0, NULL, (void *)pkeykey);
    //result = PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey(dsa_privatekey_file, dsa, EVP_des_ede3_cbc(), (unsigned char *) pkeykey, strlen(pkeykey), NULL, NULL);
    //result = PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey(dsa_privatekey_file, dsa, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    result = PEM_write_DSA_PUBKEY(dsa_publickey_file, dsa);

    fclose(dsa_privatekey_file);
    fclose(dsa_publickey_file);

    DSA_free(dsa);

    dsa_publickey_file = fopen("dsapub.pem", "r");
    dsa_privatekey_file = fopen("dsapriv.pem", "r");
}

DSA *dsa_sign = PEM_read_DSAPrivateKey(dsa_privatekey_file, NULL, default_set_password, (void *)pkeykey);

DSA *dsa_verify = PEM_read_DSA_PUBKEY(dsa_publickey_file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Here's the simple function I use to hard insert the password, but anyway it seems not to be called.

```
static int default_set_password(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *descr){ memcpy(buf, descr, size); return size; }
```

Comment: Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1):

A call to

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
```

was needed to work as expected.